# Inserting a JSON in Firebase is showing up as a String instead of appearing as tree

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Inserting a json string from a node script to firebase is showing up as following in firebase as opposed to appearing as a tree.

```
-KULCbWEdQNO_tc3tiH8: 
"{\"name\":\"Tom\",\"age\":\"42\",\"email\":\"t@t.com\",\"gen..."
```

Following json is posted to a node rest api.

```
{"name" :"Tom","age" :"42","email" :"t@t.com","gender":"Male","bloodgroup" :"A+", "foodtype" :"Non-Veg", "sleephours" :"6", "alcohol" :"Yes","smoking" :"No","diethistory" :"None"}
```

Following is the rest api code

```
.post(function(req,res){

        var user = JSON.stringify(req.body)
        var db = firebase.database();
        var usersRef = db.ref("users");
    usersRef.push(user, function(err) {
...
    }
})
```

I tried pushing the key with some dummy data and tried to update/set on success. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You call `JSON.stringify()` on the JSON object, which turns it into a string. You then insert that string into the database.

If you want to store the actual JSON object itself into the database, don't stringify it:

```
.post(function(req,res){
    var user = req.body;
    var db = firebase.database();
    var usersRef = db.ref("users");
    usersRef.push(user, function(err) {
        ...
    }
})
```